# Where to deploy Angular frontend when you're using Cloud Run as your backend?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, architecture, google-cloud-run

Currently, I have a Spring Web Kotlin backend running on Cloud Run.

I have an angular 8 frontend I developed (and plan to have other frontends) and I want to find out where do I deploy it, and connect to my backend.

Where in Google Cloud Platform I should serve/deploy the frontend? In another Cloud run (how do they communicate internally?) Or in a CDN?

Comment: The best answer depends on details not in your question. Are you using a custom domain?  Does your frontend handle CORS? How is the frontend communicating with the backend?

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy your static code in a component that host and serve static files. You have several solution

- [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)
- [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard) by defining only [static route in the handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files#configuring_your_static_file_handlers) (Here runtime don't matter, you serve only static component!)
- [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) (with a [Global Load Balancer in front of it for serving your website in HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers))

I don't recommend you to serve your static document in Cloud Run, you will pay processing time for nothing!

For the communication between the front-end and the backend, you will have to customize CORS in your app deployed on Cloud Run for this.

Comment: I add actually say that you can serve the static files from the Cloud Run service, but you should add a CDN like Cloudflare on top of it, so that they are cached.